# Can repeatedly touching the screen of a Macbook Air damage it?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, screen

I have a 2011 MacBook Air. Are there technical/physical reasons why it might be harmful to have the screen repeatedly touched or pressed? Why or why not?

Comment: Are you asking for opinions on screen touching vs. no screen touching or are you asking if there are technical reasons screens shouldn't be touched. The former is not a good question for the site, the latter is fine.

Comment: @IanC. The latter one.

Answer (score 1):

Touching your screen shouldn't do any permanent damage (unless you scratch the screen with a nail) any smudges can be wiped off with a microfibre cloth.

Using a shirt or tie to clean your screen however can damage it, so always use a glasses cloth or microfibre cloth to clean it.

Comment: Macbook Air screen is quite flimsy, applying pressure on it results in some scary color waves on the LCD. Are you sure it can't cause permanent damage?

Comment: Unless you're pushing stupidly hard, it won't damage it, best not to though.

Answer (score 0):

I have had my macbook air for about 5 months now and I have recently noticed a couple white dots on the screen, just a couple. I think this is from touching the screen but i'm not very sure. Im very annoyed...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please don't add comments in the _Answer_ field as this is for answers to questions. If you have a different question, ask it by clicking on [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you can also add a [bounty](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to get more users interested in the question. You can also read [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve your chances on getting a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, pressing the screen can't damage the mac's interior, unless you're pressing very hard on the screen, but scraping the screen with you're nail is bad for your device. DO NOT scrape on the edges of your screen or dig into the bit inside the edge of the mac's screen.
 I would overall advise not to touch or scrape your mac with your nail.